# How can I shift the code inside a tcbinputlisting environment

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I am trying to highlight code using `minted` inside of a `newtcbinputlisting` and it is working beautifully.  Thanks to TeXExchange and many previous answers!  However, I am unable to shift the code inside the `tcolorbox` environment.  I'm so close!  I'm not sure what I am missing.

```latex
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=filePrg, number format=\arabic]{\codeFromFile}[4]{%
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=#1,
    listing file={#2},
    minted options={
        fontsize=\footnotesize,
        linenos,
        numbersep=1mm,
        breaklines=true,
        },% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
    },
    colback=pythoncodebg, 
    colframe=black!70, 
    coltitle=White, 
    coltext=Black, 
    before skip= \UofUDoubleSpace, 
    after skip= \UofUDoubleSpace, 
    code={\singlespacing}, 
    breakable, % Allows for code to continue on multiple pages
    listing only, 
    arc=1.5mm, % Curvature of line corner
    enhanced, % jigsaw,
    boxrule=0.5mm, % Border width
    size=title,
    title=\TwoSymbolsAndText{\faCode}{%
    \textbf{File program \thetcbcounter}\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\textbf{:} \textit{#3}}%
    }{\faCode},
    label=filePrg:#4
}
```

[image]

Comment: you are missing a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: I believe I answered my question below.  I'm unclear as to why ```framesep``` wasn't being recognized.

Answer (score 1):

After reading more into this, I was trying to use `framesep` and that was the incorrect approach.  Instead, I needed to insert the `xleftmargin` to specify the offset.

```latex
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=filePrg, number format=\arabic]{\codeFromFileFNS}[4]{%
    listing engine=minted, 
    minted language=#1, 
    listing file={#2}, 
    %left=5mm, 
    minted options={
        fontsize=\footnotesize, 
        linenos, 
        xleftmargin=3.25mm, 
        numbersep=2mm, 
        breaklines=true, 
        },% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
        },
    colback=pythoncodebg, 
    colframe=black!70, 
    coltitle=White, 
    coltext=Black, 
    before skip= \UofUDoubleSpace, 
    after skip= \UofUDoubleSpace, 
    code={\singlespacing}, 
    breakable, % Allows for code to continue on multiple pages
    listing only, 
    arc=1.5mm, % Curvature of line corner
    enhanced jigsaw, % ,
    boxrule=0.5mm, % Border width
    size=title,
    title=\TwoSymbolsAndText{\faCode}{%
    \textbf{File program \thetcbcounter}\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\textbf{:} \textit{#3}}%
    }{\faCode},
    label=filePrg:#4
}
```

I apologize I don't have a `mwe` as this is a massive `subfiles` project.

[image]